# Not working URL in Image source

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm using Following code.

```
<img src="http://localhost/component/my_task">
```

its not working.
Any idea, Why not?? 
how can i perform my task in joomla by image source code.

NOTE:: this link perform my task ( MYURL/My_Component/My_Task). is it possible or not??

Comment: m not using "www". n dont want to any image, I'm perfoming only my_task by this way!!

Comment: Read it now after posting my solution below, but if you don't want an image, why using the `<img>` tag?? what do you want the link to be? a task? a component?

Comment: @ Damien:: Yahh.. i dont want to image. this link perform any task ( MYURL/My_Component/My_Task)

Comment: Ok so why using the `<img>` tag? just call it as a url <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/component/task[/task params]"> component should get by iself the right task. If task is meant to return an image, than you're missing the parameters the task needs to actually return the image (unless you wrote it in another way)

Comment: @Damien:: Actually i wants, when page is display then this link is hit automatically and my task should be completed.

Comment: Then I believe you need a redisgn of this part, and run the code you need passing it to the view from the controller

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because http://www.localhost/my_task does not return a valid image.

Are you sure that you should use `www.localhost`? Remove the **www** part if you want it to point your local web server.

Comment: @Manish Yes you were when i posted my edit, check your edits. Why are you using a image for this?

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` replace www.localhost

```
<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/my_task/test.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Joomla! you could use path this way

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/path/to/your/image/image.jpg">
```

For ex, if you have your image in the default folder, it should look like

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/images/stories/myimage.jpg">.
```

The way you're doing you're not linking to an image, but to a directory....